# Showing/Hiding portlets at runtime

Tags: java, portlet, liferay-6

I'm developing a web app using liferay 6.2 server.

I have a page where i have posted 4 portlets.

I want to understand, Can we hide/show few portlets at runtime on action of other portlets.

For eg. I want to hide a portlet B on click of a button in portlet A.

- Is it possible to show/hide portlets at runtime? How? Please point me to any online reference if possible.
- Is it advisable to do it?
- If not, what is the ideal way to implement this behaviour in portlets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can use CSS to show and hide the portlets. To do that you can find out the class in the portlet B, and from the portlet A you can set display none.
Hope this help
PS-: you can also remove and add the portles programmatically from the action method of the portlet.

Comment: thnx! is handling this through css the ideal way?

Comment: If only those 4 portlets are constant on your page and are not going to change, then that would be the better approach.

Comment: ok.. one last question, how to surround a portlet by div for hiding/showing? Coz i add it through the website. ADD>Select Portlet.

Comment: You can wrap the whole content of the portlet inside a unique Id, and hide the portlet border so that the borders are not visible.. than hide the div by ID....that's all

Comment: To add on to that,you can use <portlet:namespace/> to pin point the exact portlet you want to hide or show.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can render your portlet A in the maximized mode. So that it will take up the whole page and other portlets wont be there.